# Where does hydra find its keys in Python?

Tags: configuration, fb-hydra

I'm working in the nuPlan devkit (https://github.com/motional/nuplan-devkit/tree/master/tutorials), specifically in the nuplan_framework tutorial, and I reach this error:

```
MissingConfigException: In 'default_training': Could not find 'training/vector_model'

Available options in 'training':
    training_raster_model
    training_simple_vector_model
    training_urban_driver_open_loop_model
    training_vector_model
Config search path:
    provider=hydra, path=pkg://hydra.conf
    provider=main, path=file:///home/ross/nuplan-devkit/nuplan/planning/script/config/training
    provider=hydra.searchpath in main, path=pkg://nuplan.planning.script.config.common
    provider=hydra.searchpath in main, path=pkg://nuplan.planning.script.experiments
    provider=schema, path=structured://
```

I know how to resolve it -- it comes from this line of the tutorial:

```
cfg = hydra.compose(config_name=CONFIG_NAME, overrides=[
    f'group={str(SAVE_DIR)}',
    f'cache.cache_path={str(SAVE_DIR)}/cache',
    f'experiment_name={EXPERIMENT}',
    f'job_name={JOB_NAME}',
    'py_func=train',
    '+training=vector_model',
    'scenario_builder=nuplan', #nuplan_mini',  # use nuplan mini database
    'scenario_filter.limit_total_scenarios=500',  # Choose 500 scenarios to train with
    'lightning.trainer.params.accelerator=ddp_spawn',  # ddp is not allowed in interactive environment, using ddp_spawn instead - this can bottleneck the data pipeline, it is recommended to run training outside the notebook
    'lightning.trainer.params.max_epochs=30',
    'data_loader.params.batch_size=8',
    'data_loader.params.num_workers=8',
])
```

If I change to '+training=training_vector_model', then there is no problem. But, this is my confusion -- in my filesystem, there is a 'vector_model.yaml' file, but no 'training_vector_model.yaml'. Where did the config file find this list of available options above, and where does it know to link training_vector_model to vector_model.yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finds it in the search path listed there below the options.
It collects all configs in the searchpath in the config group `training`.

My guess is that it's in

```py
CONFIG_PATH = '../nuplan/planning/script/config/training'
...
hydra.initialize(config_path=CONFIG_PATH)
```

This is relative to the notebook file itself.